# Why does the while loop not break?

Tags: c++

This program takes the name of the course, grade and the number of units of a course to calculate the grade point average. I want the program to exit the `while loop` after the user enters the letter `q` and display the phrase outside the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char name[20];
    float unit;
    float score;
    float avg = 0;
    float total = 0;
    int q=0, c=0;
    
    while (name[20]!= q)

    {
        
            cout << "Enter a Name";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Enter  score";
            cin >> score;
            cout << "Enter unit of surce";
            cin >> unit;
            avg = avg + score * unit;
            total = total + unit;

            cout << "cantinue(c) or break(q)";
            cin >> name[20];
        
        
    }

    avg = avg / total;
    cout << "gpa :" << " " << avg;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `name[20]` is the 21st item in the array, which is only of the size `20`, so that's undefined behavior. Array indexes start at 0.

Comment: `while (name[20]!= q)` and `cin >> name[20];` you are accessing the 21st item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

1. You're comparing a `char` with an `int` variable called `q`. That won't break the loop when the user enters `'q'`, it will break the loop when the player enters the character that corresponds to the value that the `q` variable stores (in your case it is probably 0 in ASCII that is `'\0'`).
2. Additionally, you're accessing a variable that is out of the bonds of the array which is Undefined Behaviour. You should write `name[19]` instead.

**Solution:**

Compare `name[19]` to `'q'` instead.

```cpp
while(name[19] != 'q')
...
std::cin >> name[19];
```

**Additional information:**

1. `using namespace std;` is considered a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).
2. During the first check of the `while` condition your `char` variable is uninitializated, which will result in Undefined Behaviour. Solve this initialazing it to some value or using a `do while` loop instead;
3. I would recommend to create an additional `char` variable to store the character that controls the exit.

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char name[20];
    float unit;
    float score;
    float avg = 0;
    float total = 0;
    char quit;

    do
    {
            std::cout << "Enter a Name: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            std::cout << "Enter  score: ";
            std::cin >> score;
            std::cout << "Enter unit of source: ";
            std::cin >> unit;
            avg = avg + score * unit;
            total = total + unit;

            std::cout << "Continue(c) or break(q): ";
            std::cin >> quit;
    } while(quit != 'q');
    avg = avg / total;
    std::cout << "gpa :" << " " << avg;
    return 0;
}
```